# gmaps4rails map shows up and then disappears

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I'm a beginner Ruby on Rails user and using gmaps4rails for the first time. I was following a youtube tutorial on how to use it but came across a problem I can't seem to fix.

My map will show up for a second and then disappear into a grey screen.

I've tried a bunch of different ways to fix it but couldn't get it to work. I've read that there are conflicts between gmaps4rails and turbolinks and bootstrap, could this be the problem?

Here is my code.

The view:

```
  <div style='width: 800px;'>
          <div id="map" style='width: 800px; height: 400px;'></div>
        </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
  handler.buildMap({ provider: {maxZoom: 2}, internal: {id: 'map'}},    function(){
  markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
      handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
      handler.fitMapToBounds();
  });

</script>
```

Here is my user controller.

```
def index
    @users = User.all
    if current_user.admin?
          @posts = User.all
    end
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@users) do |user, marker|
      marker.lat user.latitude
      marker.lng user.longitude
      marker.infowindow user.name
    end
  end
```

Here is part of my Gemfile

```
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc


gem 'rspec-rails'
gem 'guard-bundler'
gem 'guard-rspec'
gem 'factory_girl_rails'
gem 'capybara'
gem 'geocoder'
```

Here is my application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps/google
//= require_tree .


@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "jquery.datetimepicker";
@import "*";
@import "bourbon";
```

Note: While I was playing around with the code, I noticed that the map shows up when I take out the markers completely.

Please let me know if you can see what's wrong! Any help is much appreciated.